# Removing .html using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm quite new to html and I want to remove the .html , i did some research and figured out i have to edit the .htaccess.

now i have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

But when i go to www.mywebsite.com/about it shows the html text (from the html file) in my webpage.

What i see is like this: `<DOCTYPEHTML!>
<head>
<title>BETA-About me</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">`
etc.
How can i use the .htacces to remove the .html part without showing plain html text?

Comment: Eh? You want to remove the html tag? I hope you just try to remove the file ending.

Comment: What do you mean by changing html part? Do you want to run your html files as plain texts or something else?

Comment: Is <DOCTYPEHTML!> a valid html5 document type declaration?:)

Comment: @Starkeen thank you, i changed it to <!DOCTYPE html> thought the ! was on the end. but it wasn't

Comment: @rekire yes i wanted to remove the file ending so about.html becomes about. But with help of Starkeen i fixed it